# In a 2D array a[row][column] what does a[row] stand for?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to add a string to a char 2D array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
   char a[20][20]={"fire","ice","water"};
   a[3]="land";
   printf("%s",a[3]);
}
```

I get and error message saying

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
a[3]="land"; 

     ^
```

The code works if instead I use `strcpy(a[3],"land")`.
So my question is why doesn't the first code work?Isn't `a[3]` a pointer to the first element of the fourth row of the char array? If it is not a pointer,then why does `strcpy()` work even though it expects a pointer argument?
I'm a beginner and this is my first question on SO so I apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: The type of `a[3]` is not a pointer but an array of twenty characters.

Comment: You are trying to assign **address** of temporary string (`"land"`) to `a[3]`. It's not gonna work. You should use `strcpy()` for this reason.

Comment: The reason it works in the first line is that there is a special rule that causes string literals to be copied in initialisers. This doesn't apply in the second line, which is an assignment, rather than an initialisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are not assignable in C.
Yes array decays to a pointer while using `strcpy()` and `a[3]` will point to the 4th row of your 2D array.

Whereas in the case `a[3] = "land"` `a[3]` doesn't decay to a pointer.

For ex:

```
char *p;
p = "hello";
```

This is a valid assignment because p is a pointer.Whereas

```
char a[10];
a = "hello";
```

Since `a` is a array and not a pointer you will get an error for this. Note the difference between an array and a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

**Arrays are not assignable**. You must assign individual characters one by one which is what `strcpy` does.

The type of `a[i]` is `char[20]` ,i.e, an array of characters of size 20 and the type of `"land"` is `char*` , a pointer to `char`. These are not compatible types and this is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add directly a string to a char **. This is a feature usually supported by the OOP (Oriented Object Programming) languages.

"a[3]="land";" is not supported by C, you need to use a fonction that will assign each character to each char of your char *. The main one is strcpy() (man strcpy).